# Can we used the iOS technologies in apple watch app?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I want to create music app in which the watch extension app shows audio wave so my question is Can we used the iOS technologies like `openGL` in watch app?

Comment: This is a near-identical copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803180/can-we-use-ios-technologies-in-apple-watch-app from http://stackoverflow.com/users/1468406/pratik-bhiyani, what's going on here?  Are both accounts the same person?

Comment: it's my friends account we are working in same office.it was deleted and i asked from my account again. Do you have any problem ?

Comment: It just looked a little suspicious is all

Answer (score 4):

You can't run any code on the watch.  You can only run code in a Watch extension in your iOS app and update a relatively static UI on the watch.  You could generate images in your extension for the audio wave, put them together into an animation and then update the UI with that.

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible to pass some information from your iOS app to the Watch extension running on the phone, which could then update a pre-defined interface on the Watch app. However, if you are wanting to provide a real-time audio waveform, I think this could face major problems regarding latency.

Note that as Stephen Johnson states, you could only do this by rendering static images which would then be sent to the watch for display, or by having pre-installed images in your watch interface that you rapidly show or hide to give the impression of levels changing. The latter would be a much more promising approach from a latency approach, and given Apple give a demonstration of a circular progress indicator made up of 360 images, perhaps it would appear to animate smoothly even. However, the key question would be whether the peaks would appear on the Watch screen close enough to when they actually occurred in the music that the user would see them as being linked.

It might be possible to pre-process the audio and build in a delay to both the display of the peaks and the audio playback to manage the communication latency—but testing that would really only be possible once you had Watch hardware in your hand.

Comment: Can you point to that demonstration of the circular progress indicator?